# Is it true that Canada doesn't stamp foreign passports by default?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, passport-stamps

I recently sent the CBSA (Canadian border agency) an e-mail asking whether one would get two or just one entry stamp if first entering Canada by air, then going to the US by land for two days and then returning to Canada by land.

To my big surprise, I got the following Reply (from CBSA-ASFC.CONTACT@cbsa-asfc.gc.ca):

> As a matter of procedure, passports are not normally stamped

Is this really true (whether at airports or land borders)? I've seen lots of Canadian passport stamps online (which do seem to vary in look depending on the port of entry). Were all of these specifically requested, or what?

If it matters, I'm a visa-free EU national. To clarify, I would not find it negative - quite the opposite, if CBSA's info were to be accurate.

Anyone with recent experience?

Comment: Why wouldn't this be true if answered directly from them ? Maybe they are stamped when the person who come in needs a visa ?

Comment: Did you mention your citizenship when you asked ? Canadian and US passport holders indeed do not get their passports stamped

Comment: @blackbird Yep, I started by message with "To whom it may concern: I am a citizen of Sweden and am planning to..."

Comment: It all depends what "normally" means. If 80% of passports processed are Canadian or American and do not get stamped, then "normally" may simply apply to that share of not stamped passports. And your case would not be "normal".

Comment: @blackbird by land perhaps, but I've certainly received stamps on my US passport when entering Canada by air, without requesting one.

Comment: @phoog I had to explicitly request one when crossing via rainbow bridge (US citizen). Just to add to anecdotes.

Comment: To add to the anecdotes, my passport has not been stamped a single time entering Canada by air.

Comment: @MarcksThomas what country issued your passport?

Comment: More anecdotes: I (an American) had a resident permit and lived in Vancouver for a year. I crossed the WA/BC border a dozen times, never stamped, and was only stamped when I flew into Toronto from DC, and that was with my permit.

Comment: I live in (and am a citizen of) the USA, an hour from the Canadian border. I've driven across the border dozens of times, and my passport has never been stamped. Once my friend *requested* that hers be stamped, and the customs agent did humor her by honoring her wish.

Comment: I have not had my passport stamped. I drive over one of the Buffalo area bridges and I'm a US citizen.

Comment: Just arrived in Canada yesterday. I am from Australia, another Commonwealth country with a visa waiver plan with Canada. I travelled via the US with a layover. My passport was not stamped at Canada.

Comment: Three entries into Canada since I retired.  All stamped.  U.S. passport.

Comment: I am a Swiss citizen with student permit in Canada and my passport was not stamped when I re-entered (July 2018) arriving from Germany. Confused, I went back to the airport and asked a border control officer who told me that they don't stamp anymore.

Comment: @ThomasZuberbühler What Airport?

Comment: Halifax Airport

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**That's not true**, and I suspect they either misunderstood your question (did they think you're a US citizen?) or there's some context we're missing.

Source: I've entered Canada at least a dozen times, using two different nationalities. I've gotten a stamp every single time, including even a direct transit to an international flight via Vancouver.

Comment: @pnuts for the moment only US and Canadian citizens can use automated passport control, if other nationalities don't get stamped how would anyone keep track of entries and exits ? Canada doesn't do exit immigration so there's no way around an entry stamp

Comment: @pnuts The last time I was in Canada was this past Saturday, on the transit in question, and I was stamped!

Comment: @jpatokal I told them in the beginning of the message I was Swedish.

Comment: @blackbird, Your passport gets scanned whether you use a machine or see an officer, so that doesn't make much difference. CBSA does have electronic records of entries, it is possible to obtain them (by sending a request on paper). Canadian PRs applying for extensions or citizenship sometimes do this since CIC has been known to dispute one's self-reported time in the country based on passport stamps, which the CBSA doesn't reliably provide. For visitors only the CBSA is likely interested in when you entered and they already know.

Comment: @blackbird that's not true! You missed Canadian PRs, I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 10):

I've flown several times into Canada and have received a stamp each time.

I've also had to state my business and my job back home each time. UK citizen.

Comment: Consider removing or updating your answer as it is no longer factual (see my answer below).

Comment: @JonathanReez Strange. I received a stamp flying into Halifax YHZ in March 2018

Comment: @davidb I didn't receive one flying into Halifax in July 2018

Answer (score 7):

At the YVR airport you can use a machine if you are either

- a Canadian resident
- have a US passport
- have a Canadian passport

although you need to meet the border guard after, you will never get a stamp, it's pretty much impossible, they are standing there and have nothing to stamp on.

On the other hand, everyone else who meets the normal process does get a stamp. I have seen this with my own eyes standing in the queue more times in the last eight years than I want to admit.

Comment: As a Canadian citizen, my passport does not get stamped even when I go straight to the officer (no machine).

Comment: It's not the border guard you meet after it's customs, they have no reason to stamp your passport

Comment: Are you sure? These guys check my passport. The customs declaration card is collected after you collect your baggage. Also, I once claimed I have stuff I mailed and they redirected me to the window. it doesn't seem like customs to me but what do I know.

Comment: @blackbird, The ABC machines don't verify biometrics so [you still see a person to match you to your travel document](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/abc-cfa-eng.html). US APC machines work the same way. At YYZ the people serving that queue are not at a desk and don't have a stamp.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Most countries don't stamp their own citizens for logical reasons, so nothing remarkable

Comment: @Crazydre: do you have a source for "most"? I'm a citizen of two, one stamps, the other one doesn't.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Observations from lots of travel worldwide

Comment: @Dennis APC kiosks definitely verify biometrics, both the face and (for non-Americans/Canadians) fingerprints. However, the officer matches your face against the document and (for visitors) do a landing interview (at least in my experience)

Answer (score 7):

Things are [changing](http://www.gands.com/knowledge-centre/firmnews/news-item/2017/05/17/canadian-immigration-officers-not-stamping-passports-anymore) since 2017:

> While the official Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada (IRCC) website still indicates that officers will stamp entry dates on  passports when individuals arrive in Canada, it is our understanding that this practice has stopped at some ports of entry and will stop soon at all ports of entry.   As IRCC moves toward electronic tracking of entry and exists into Canada, the practice of manual stamping of passports will eventually be stopped.

I can confirm that flying into Vancouver Airport with a visa or ETA you won't get a passport stamp as of 2018. Likewise from personal experience you don't get a passport stamp when entering Canada by car, bus or rail. So I'm pretty sure the practice has been abolished at all Canadian entry points.

Comment: `So I'm pretty sure the practice has been abolished at all Canadian entry points.` Not at all correct. Just because you didn't get stamped amounts to nothing. They still stamp passports at Vancouver airport for visas/ETA. I saw many get stamped, including myself (Nov 2018). So your generalization is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

I recently drove into Canada and I got a stamp in my passport (UK). Obviously it doesn't mean they always put a stamp :).

Answer (score 4):

Driving or ferrying into BC from various crossings in Washington State I have never received a stamp. Driving into Yukon from Alaska I have received a stamp each time. Using a US Passport.

Comment: Clearly Americans can cross land borders without ever getting stamped since they can use documents (NEXUS, passport card, EDL, birth certificate) that can't be stamped. It is hence unusual for them to bother with a stamp when the document happens to be a passport. I wonder whether the reliable stamps at the Yukon border are saying something about the reliability of the electronic record collection there, or are just a symptom of CBSA border officers not having enough work to do.

Comment: @Dennis my impression was the latter. They always seem happy to see someone. :-)

Comment: @Crazydre one third of former Yugoslav countries *are* in the EU.  I guess you meant meant to limit your comment to the other four.  I've also found that stamping (and document inspection) practice varies considerably depending on whether one is crossing a land border or entering at an airport.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this is the case. I entered Canada at YVR two weeks ago and my (US) passport was *not* stamped. Previously when I entered at YUL in 2012 and 2013 it *was* stamped. Whether this is a recent policy change or just the Quebecois like to stamp things, I do not know.

Comment: 2012 predates the automated passport control at YUL, everyone but Canadian citizens likely got their passports stamped. Did you use a kiosk at YVR ?

Answer (score 2):

i recently went to Canada on may of 2018. am from the Caribbean so i have a Canadian visa. upon arrival and on our departure we never got our passports stamped.

Comment: Ditto coming from Amsterdam into Montreal. Nobody even looked at my passport, machines all the way, no stamp. Customs official just asked if I'd anything to declare, then wished me a pleasant stay.

Comment: @jwenting WHat's your citizenshsip? Given that you used a kiosk? Also, did no one actually check the receipt the kiosk (presumably) spat out?

Comment: @Coke I'm Dutch. The receipt was collected by a disinterested guy at the entrance to the luggage hall, the customs guy just asked me if I'd filled it out truthfully but didn't have it (or indeed any such receipts), didn't ask my passport, didn't ask my name.

Comment: @jwenting So everyone's eligible for the kiosk now? Or did you get any info on that?

Comment: @Coke EU, Canadian, and US people were directed one way, others another way. So I guess it depends on your nationality, ETA status, and maybe other things.

Comment: @jwenting Ah, wonder whether they count EFTA as "EU" in their minds, ie would've directed eg a Norwegian person to the kiosks as well xD