# Visa to Canada Necessary?

Tags: visas, canada

I am a USA permanent resident. In 2009 while an H1B worker in the USA, I applied for a visa to visit Canada. The consular officer requested information clarifying my legal status in the USA. I never went back for the visa because I was temporarily out of status at the time and didn't have the evidence required. I never received any indication that the visa was denied.

I want to visit Canada now. **Would applying for a visa be suspicious/advisable considering USA permanent residents are allowed to visit without a visa**?

I would prefer having a visa stamp in my passport because I plan to return to my home country for good within a year and give up my USA green card. Having once received a Canadian visa would be beneficial at that point in my application for visas to other countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some points you might like to consider:

1. What happens if you apply and are refused (even if in part because never necessary in the first place)?
2. How much track record weight is a Canadian visa going to add to an H1-B?
3. [Is it true that Canada doesn't stamp foreign passports by default?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80224/is-it-true-that-canada-doesnt-stamp-foreign-passports-by-default)
4. [CBSA Travel History Report](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/agency-agence/reports-rapports/pia-efvp/atip-aiprp/thr-rav-eng.html).
5. Cost and hassle v. likely benefit.